# NSUserDefault issue

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I am creating a divelog app.  When someone select a new dive, they will get an alert with two options: "Blank template" or "Use last dive as template".
The issue is with the later, last dive as a template.

Each dive I record the data to the NSUserDefaults.  So, when someone wants last dive as a template, I just call each of the defaults and populate the tableview.

However, I am getting a nil error on the first field, the diveSiteTextfield.text, this baffles me:

Here is where the data gets saved to NSUserDefaults

As you can see, I added a print command to test to see if the diveSite field is nil, but it displays the correct data.  The diveSiteTextfield.text is not nil.

```
import UIKit
import Parse


var diveUUID = NSUUID().UUIDString

class DiveDetails1VC: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource
{
    let userDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    @IBOutlet weak var ratingControl: DiveSiteRating!
    @IBOutlet weak var diveSiteTextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var diveDurationTextfield: UITextField!

...

func toDive2NewParse () {

    let diveObject = PFObject(className: "divelog")

        diveObject["diveNumber"]        = diveNumberInt
        diveObject["diveSite"]          = diveSiteTextfield.text
        diveObject["diveDuration"]      = diveDurationTextfield.text
        diveObject["maxDepth"]          = diveMaxDepthTextfield.text
        diveObject["diveDate"]          = diveDateTextfield.text
        diveObject["diveTime"]          = diveTimeTextfield.text
        diveObject["bodyOfWater"]       = diveBodyOfWaterTextfield.text
        diveObject["diveBuddy"]         = diveBuddyTextfield.text
        diveObject["diveCity"]          = diveCityTextfield.text
        diveObject["maxDepthSymbol"]    = diveMaxDepthSymbolTextField.text
        diveObject["diveCountry"]       = diveCountryTextField.text
        diveObject["uuid"] = "\(diveUUID)"

        //        diveObject["diveRating"]          = ratingControl


            diveObject["entryFrom"] = "Divelog"

            if PFUser.currentUser()!.username == nil {
                diveObject["username"] = "Not Signed in"
            } else {
            diveObject["username"] = PFUser.currentUser()!.username
            }
            diveObject.saveEventually()

        userDefault.setObject(diveNumberInt, forKey: "diveNumber")
        userDefault.setObject(diveSiteTextfield.text, forKey: "diveSite")
        userDefault.setObject(diveDurationTextfield.text!, forKey: "diveDuration")
        userDefault.setObject(diveMaxDepthTextfield.text, forKey: "diveDepth")
        userDefault.setObject(diveMaxDepthSymbolTextField.text, forKey: "symbol_maxDepth")
        userDefault.setObject(diveDateTextfield.text, forKey: "entryDate")
        userDefault.setObject(diveTimeTextfield.text, forKey: "entryTime")
        userDefault.setObject(diveCityTextfield.text, forKey: "diveCity")
        userDefault.setObject(diveCountryTextField.text, forKey: "diveCountry")
        userDefault.setObject(diveBodyOfWaterTextfield.text, forKey: "bodyOfWater")
        userDefault.setObject(diveBuddyTextfield.text, forKey: "diveBuddy")
        userDefault.setObject(diveUUID, forKey: "uuid")
        userDefault.synchronize()

    print("DiveSite is ...\(userDefault.objectForKey("diveSite"))")
}
```

Here is the UIAlertAction that retrieves the "last dive":

```
@IBAction func addNewDive (sender: AnyObject) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "New Dive", message: "Choose a template", preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)
    let buttonOne = UIAlertAction(title: "Blank template", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in


        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueNewDive1", sender: self)

        print("Button One Pressed")
    })
    let buttonTwo = UIAlertAction(title: "Use last dive as template", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

        self.VC1.diveSiteTextfield.text = self.userDefault.stringForKey("diveSite")
        self.VC1.diveDurationTextfield.text = self.userDefault.stringForKey("diveDuration")
        self.VC1.diveMaxDepthTextfield.text = self.userDefault.stringForKey("diveDepth")
 ...
        self.DNo.textView.text = self.userDefault.objectForKey("diveNotes") as? String;
        self.userDefault.synchronize()


        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueNewDive1", sender: self)
```

any help on understanding why the nil will be greatly appreciated.

Updated with Vladian's comment

Comment: First of all there is a method `stringForKey:` to read string values and second of all `synchronize` is not needed after writing to and completely wrong after reading from user defaults.

Comment: And in the retrieve part, what gives a print userDefaults.objectForKey("diveSite") ?

Comment: Thanks, @Vadian I will try that.  Thanks for the sync comment.  Logical, just missed that.

Comment: @FredericP.  This prints the text I type into the diveSiteTextField on the simulator.  It is displaying the correct data.

Comment: The values are clearly supposed to be `String`, so what is the purpose to use a generic method and cast it to `String` anyway? The strong type system of Swift encourages the developer to code as specific as possible, not the other way round.

Comment: You are right.  I misread the comment the first time.

Comment: Doesn't a nil seem odd.  This is a string, wouldn't just be blank if an error?  Why the nil?

Comment: Question:  I am using two controllers.  Master and VC1.  Master is asking if blank or previous template to prepopulate VC1 if they want last dive as template.  is it possible the nil is caused by trying to populate VC1 before it is called?

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` works similar to a dictionary. If the key does not exist you get `nil`. You can avoid that – as recommended by Apple – by registering non-nil default values. PS: I'm not `Vlad*ian* the Impaler`

Comment: That is what is was.  I moved the userDefault lines to the VC1 with an if statement and it worked fine.

Comment: @Vlad\*ian\* the Impaler, as you inspired and pushed me to solve this, post the answer and I will confirm it.